# VS2015 Error while trying to run application: Invalid Pointer

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015, invalid-pointer

When you debug a Visual Studio 2015 solution you see this error message:

> Error while trying to run application: Invalid pointer

Obviously something isn't configured properly, or is permissions related, just wondering if anyone has identified the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Jeremy's advice I reviewed the Activity Log (See here for info about the Activity Log) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166359.aspx

and found this error in the stack trace

```
....Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Visual Studio\14.0\TraceDebugging\' is denied.]:...
```

The directory did not exist so I created it and was thereafter able to debug the project without the error.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to start Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator

**Right click the Visual Studio 2015 shortcut file or start menu item > Run As Administrator**

Comment: I still have an invalid pointer: The operation could not be completed. Have an MVC webapplication. Do you have the update 1 for vs15?

Comment: No, I don't have the update. Check out what's in the VS Activity Log for clues to fix it. Based on the Admin workaround I reckon the problem is registry related so run ProcMon for anything out of the ordinary