# project won't run on visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So after formatting my pc I reinstalled Visual studio 2015 and loaded all my projects,all of them runs fine instead of one that was created in VS 2013 ,
when trying to run the project it builds successfully but will not run instead I get the error

> invalid pointer

and that is all after some digging I looked at the activity log and I see this error :

```
      <entry>
    <record>795</record>
    <time>2016/12/29 23:53:42.037</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage]</description>
    <guid>{494B203E-3C94-40AB-B331-6CB32460B617}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>796</record>
    <time>2016/12/29 23:53:42.037</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage..ctor()&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean&amp; canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal&amp; ctor, Boolean&amp; bNeedSecurityCheck)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage..ctor()&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{494B203E-3C94-40AB-B331-6CB32460B617}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

didn't find many places talking about this but from what I found I tried these suggestions:

1) renamed the profile directory

> C:\Users\blabla\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

2) deleted the registry key associated with the error GUID

but nothing is working any help would be appreciated.

PS: the project I'm trying to load is Windows 8.1 App built with c# with Xaml

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript?

Comment: mm I can't see the connection the project is a windows 8.1 app built with c# with Xaml Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for Javascript shouldn't have an effect but no harm in trying , I edited the post to better show what project I'm trying to run thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use "Users" folders. Create one in C:\Projects....

Comment: tried that now but its not solving the problem thanks though

Comment: Check on it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270428/vs2015-error-while-trying-to-run-application-invalid-pointer

Comment: No but from my little research it seems this package has something to do with intellisence

Comment: I did come across this one but also with no luck